# clojure.core/map behaving in a very surprising manner

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

```
(map :one '({:one "one"}))
;; ("one")
(map :name '(r b))
;; (nil nil)
(:name r)
;; "Steve"
(map :one '({:one "one"} {:one "two"}))
;; ("one" "two")
r
;; {:color :red, :name "Steve"}
```

Map, as you can see here, seems to work as expected for a list of hashmaps but for maps that have been bound to the symbol `r` and `b`, map returns `nil`.

What's going on here, why doesn't map return the correct value for `r` (Which IMO should be the string "Steve")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to `'(r b)`, you're getting the literal symbols `r` and `b`, not the maps they resolve to.

Here you're invoking `(:name 'r)` and that returns `nil`.